# Double Click Function for Key Listener using Arrays and Array lists in java counts everything as a double click

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, keylistener, double-click

The java KeyListener class has no option for a double key press, so I attempted to make my own using multiple arrays and arraylists.

Here is the relevent code

```
    private ArrayList<Integer> ButtonsPressedChar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Long> ButtonsPressedTimes = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private int[] PossiblePresses = new int[222];
    private ArrayList<Integer> DoublePresses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> ToBeRemovedChars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> ToBeRemovedTimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
    private Long LastTimeForDoublePress;
    private Long NowTime;
    private int PositionTime;
    private int PositionChar;

    public void DetectDoubleKeyPresses(){
        PositionTime = 0;
        PositionChar = 0;
        NowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int temp : PossiblePresses){
            PossiblePresses[temp] = 0;                    
        }
        for(Long temp: ButtonsPressedTimes){
            if( temp - NowTime >= 300){
                ButtonsPressedChar.remove(PositionTime);
                ToBeRemovedTimes.add(PositionTime);
                System.out.println("removed");                         
            }
            PositionTime++;
        }
        for(int temp: ToBeRemovedTimes){
            ButtonsPressedTimes.remove(temp);
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
        DoublePresses.clear();
        for(Integer temp: ButtonsPressedChar){
            System.out.println("hi 1");
            if( PossiblePresses[temp] == 0){
                System.out.println("First Press" + temp + PossiblePresses[temp]);
                PossiblePresses[temp] = 2;
            }
            else if(PossiblePresses[temp] == 2){
                DoublePresses.add(temp);
                System.out.println(ButtonsPressedChar.size());
                ToBeRemovedChars.add(temp);
                ButtonsPressedTimes.remove(PositionChar);
                System.out.println("DOUBLE PRESS" + temp.toString()+ PossiblePresses[temp]);
            }
            System.out.println("hi 2");
            PositionChar++;
        }
        for(Integer temp: ToBeRemovedChars){
            while(ButtonsPressedChar.contains(temp)){
                ButtonsPressedChar.remove(temp);
            }
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
        ToBeRemovedChars.clear();
        LastTimeForDoublePress =NowTime;
    }

public class Keys implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(ButtonsHeld.contains(e.getKeyCode())){
            Integer tempInteger = new Integer(e.getKeyCode());
            ButtonsHeld.remove(tempInteger);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("ERROR");               
        System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
        ButtonsPressedChar.add( e.getKeyCode());
        ButtonsPressedTimes.add(System.currentTimeMillis())               
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(ButtonsHeld.contains(e.getKeyCode())){               
            System.out.println("Error: Attempted Key Press Twice, original press was not removed from ButtonsHeld");
        }     
        else if(!ButtonsHeld.contains(e.getKeyCode())){
            ButtonsHeld.add(e.getKeyCode());
        }
    }     

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> ButtonsHeld = new ArrayList<Integer>();          
    public void KeyHeldChecker(){               
        }          
 }
```

I'm so sorry if some of the brackets are in weird places, i had to adjust everything to get it in the code block

Detect Double Key presses is executed 60 times a second. The 'hi 1' and 'hi 2' were just part of my debugging to see what was being executed. This is what is executed when J (key code 74) is pressed a single time:

```
74
hi 1
First press740
hi 2
hi 1
1
DOUBLE PRESS742
hi 2
DONE
```

At first i thought possible presses was not being cleared properly, but the for loop seems to be working. If anyone knows why this isn't working or even just a better way of doing this that would be amazing.

Sorry for the bad format, I honestly can't get it to work and are not finding any quadruple spaces anywhere they shouldn't be. I hope that it doesn't make it too hard to see or understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to detect a simple double press there is no real need for any arrays or Arraylists. You only need to really store the previous key press.

Consider this: If you press <kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>J</kbd> the J is no longer a double press so why do you care about it.

To do this you could use the following:

```
public class DoubleKeyPressDetection
{
     // Below int is the number of milliseconds between the presses to determine 
     // if it was an intentional double press 
     // Adjust this for sensitivity required
    private static int doublePressSpeed = 500; // Half a second
    private static KeyEvent lastKeyEvent;

    public static  boolean isDoublePress(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        KeyEvent temp = lastKeyEvent;
        lastKeyEvent = ke;
        return temp != null
            && temp.getKeyCode() == ke.getKeyCode()
            && ((ke.getWhen() - temp.getWhen()) < doublePressSpeed);
    }
}
```

Then in your `KeyListener`

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(DoubleKeyPressDetection.isDoublePress(e))
        System.out.println("You have double pressed " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}
```

Points to note:

- If you put this in both the `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` methods then it will action on every keyPress and release - so will not work correctly
- If you use the `keyTyped` method then this might not work as the `KeyEvent` does not have the keyCode
- Not all keys will be tracked by this (depending on your application i.e. <kbd>Tab</kbd> in a swing app)

Comment: Sorry Java devil, I should have been more specific. The reason I need this is to detect a double press in a two player game, with two people using the keyboard they could interfere with each other, or someone could even interfere with themselves pressing multiple buttons. P.S. the double press is for a dash function

Comment: Java devil couldn't one player double press while the other player double presses, interfering with the double click program. If you know how to do that it would be awesome, but if you know why it isn't working that would be even better

Comment: @SamChapman Yes I see, they could interfere with each others presses. Well if this is the case then I assume that each player only has set keys so you could make my example non static and then have an instance of the detection class for each player and in your listener determine what player the key press was for and reference that players detection instance. Sorry I don't have time right now to draft something up for you.

Comment: that sounds perfect. I can't believe I didn't think of it. I got it working in the end, so I'll post it here as the answer, thanks for all the advice.